# Compiller error - End binding failed: Bad value

Tags: drivers, compiling, make

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

I'm compiling a driver to control LED via serial, but it gave the following error at the end of the compilation:

```
/usr/bin/ld: dl_free_download.o: R_X86_64_PC32 relocation against symbol "dl_download_data" cannot be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makeup: ***
[Makefile:65: libdatalink.so.1] Error 1
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggested (*"recompile with -fPIC"*)?